# createNewFile( ) causes warning message, how to eliminate?

Tags: java, file, warnings

By using `createNewFile` method and delete method of the `File` class I successfully generate files from my program. But there is an annoying warning message after the compilation process. My question is how can I remove that warning messages without using `@SUPPRESSWARNIGN`. Because when I do inspection for my code I see a probable bug warnings which are caused by these 2 methods. Yes, by using `@SuppressWarning` warnings and probable bug messages go away.

I do not know if it is related with the Java version but in any case I am using Java 8. I did the research for this problem, could not find anything on the internet. I saw people on the internet used these 2 methods in the same way I used. May be they ignored the warning messages. But I do not want to.

Here is my code :

```
private void createAFile() throws IOException {

    String outputFileName = getFileName();
    String outputPathName = getFilePath();
    String fullOutputPath = outputPathName + "/" + outputFileName;

    output = new File(fullOutputPath);

    if(output.exists()){

        output.delete(); //this returns a boolean variable.

    }

    output.createNewFile(); //this also return a boolean variable.


}
```

Warnings are :

Warning:(79, 20) Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored.
Warning:(84, 16) Result of 'File.createNewFile()' is ignored.

Thank you

Comment: It would *really* help if you said *what* those warnings are.

Comment: I don't see any warning with that code in Java 8.

Comment: Warning:(79, 20) Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored. And Warning:(84, 16) Result of 'File.createNewFile()' is ignored

Answer (score 11):

If you want to avoid these messages you can provide logging for the case when these method return false.

Something like this

```
private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("myClassName");
// some code
if (!output.delete()) {
  LOG.info("Cannot delete file: " + output);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the log idea :) right now can not vote up, sorry for that.

Answer (score 7):

These look like warnings generated from a code check tool . What i would do is this :

```
boolean deleted,created; // both should be instantiatd to false by default
if(output.exists()){

   deleted = output.delete(); //this returns a boolean variable.
} 
if(deleted){ 
    created = output.createNewFile();
}
if(!deleted||!created){
    // log some type of warning here or even throw an exception
}
```

Comment: thank you :) Since I am newbie in the Stackoverflow I can not vote up your answer. But I am voting up your answer "abstractly".